# Из строки в виде шестнадцатеричного числа получить массив байтов

Tags: c#

Например у меня есть такая строка `"A329DF34"`. Как ее превратить в массив из 4 байтов?

Конечно можно разделить ее на части по 2, дальше каждую часть превратить в число от `0` до `255`, а затем сохранить результат в виде байт массива. Но может есть стандартное решение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Простое решение "в лоб"

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string hex = "A329DF34";
    byte[] bytes = new byte[hex.Length / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
        bytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", bytes));
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
163, 41, 223, 52
```

---

Альтернативаное решение, если в массиве ровно 4 байта

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string hex = "A329DF34";
    uint number = Convert.ToUInt32(hex, 16);
    byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(number);
    Array.Reverse(bytes);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", bytes));
}
```

---

Для **.NET 5** и новее, есть встроенное решение

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string hex = "A329DF34";
    byte[] bytes = Convert.FromHexString(hex);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", bytes));
}
```

Больше разных решений можно найти [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/q/321370/12888024).