# Как отформатировать hex значения

Tags: c#, tcp

Как записать hex из строки  чтобы в байты корректно конвертировались их можно было нормально читать а не как у меня все кучу так выглядят строка байтов  из wireshark:

02 30 00 80 00 01 11 11 ad 09 01 00 00 00 60 8c
90 02 01 20 05 00 10 80 00 00 00 02 42 00 02 05
dc 00 00 00 11 00 00 12 b2 09 02 00 00 00 60 8c
91 02 01 20 05 00 10 00 00 00 00 02 40 00 01 05
de 00 00 00 11 00 00 b1 b0 00 00 c8 13 02 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 11 b2 af 00 00 c8 13 02 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 11 b3 b1 00 60 88 10 02 10 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 11 b4 ae 00 60 88 10 02 10 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 11 00 01 00 01 10 49 03

**Mой код**

```
private void Send(MyClient obj)
        {
            Log($"Train->PTU:Create Menu");
            //byte[] Send = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("02-20-00-01-11-00-01-00-00-03-00-00")
            byte[] Send = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("02-30-00-80-00-01-11-11-ad-09-01-00-00-00-60-8c-90-02-01-20-05-00-10-80-00-00-00-02-42-00-02-05-dc-00-00-00-11-00-00-12-b2-09-02-00-00-00-60-8c-91-02-01-20-05-00-10-00-00-00-00-02-40-00-01-05-de-00-00-00-11-00-00-b1-b0-00-00-c8-13-02-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-11-b2-af-00-00-c8-13-02-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-11-b3-b1-00-60-88-10-02-10-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-11-b4-ae-00-60-88-10-02-10-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-11-00-01-00-01-10-49-03");
            obj.stream.Write(Send, 0, Send.Length);
        }
```

Comment: Массив байтов их  и так я получаю все збито в одну строку. Тяжело читать такую строку.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```cs
string hex = "02-30-00-80-00-01-11-11-ad-09-01-00-00-00-60-8c-90-02-01-20-05-00-10-80-00-00-00-02-42-00-02-05-dc-00-00-00-11-00-00-12-b2-09-02-00-00-00-60-8c-91-02-01-20-05-00-10-00-00-00-00-02-40-00-01-05-de-00-00-00-11-00-00-b1-b0-00-00-c8-13-02-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-11-b2-af-00-00-c8-13-02-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-11-b3-b1-00-60-88-10-02-10-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-11-b4-ae-00-60-88-10-02-10-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-11-00-01-00-01-10-49-03";
hex = hex.Replace("-", "");
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromHexString(hex);
```

`FromHexString` - требуется .NET 5 и выше.

Comment: Пишет что в Convert нету  FromHexString.

Comment: @Vladimir нужен .NET 5.

Comment: @Vladimir https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1284503/373567 вот еще варианты

Comment: Cпасибо вам  я все варианты  рассмотрю.

Comment: Я очень вам благодарен. Все заработало.